# Can someone help me understand what the と particle is doing in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

I'm fairly certain the と particle here is the conditional form. But I could be totally wrong.

それが真実であると仮定しよう。

The translation I have for it is, "Let's suppose it is true". But it seems odd to me that と is being used conditionally. Wouldn't it transliterate to something like, "If it is true, let's suppose"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This と is a *quotative*-と, not conditional.

> それが真実であると仮定しよう。
> Let's assume that it is true.

A conditional-と cannot be used with (し)よう in the first place. Something like 雨が降ると家にいよう is already ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

The と used here is not conditional form.
The usage here is defined as follows:

⑥（発話・思考を表す動詞とともに使って）**発話・思考の内容を示す**。（明鏡国語辞典）
と is used to indicate the content of one's thought or speech when used with a verb like think, speak,etc.

それが真実であると仮定しよう。Here, と means 「それが真実である」is the content of 「仮定する」. Namely, Let's assume that [that is true].